# Find substring with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would our group find out if a particular string contains a certain substring? Only with the help of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), please.

Comment: Just exactly how much cowbell do you want? :-)

Comment: @npup, enough to have it working in IE, perhaps?

Comment: @Fluffy That made even less sense than my comment *awe*

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: string contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Answer (score 38):

You don't really need jQuery for such a simple thing, you can simply use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/IndexOf) method of String objects, e.g.:

```
var str = "foobar";
var containsFoo = str.indexOf('foo') >= 0; // true
```

The `indexOf` method returns the character index where the first occurrence of the specified value is encountered, if not found, it returns `-1`.

Comment: or to make it jquery like:

var containsFoo = $("#foobar").text().indexOf('foo') >= 0; // true

Comment: @Jacob, nevertheless `text()` returns a `String`

Answer (score 11):

Why use 10 characters when 100 will do?

Here's the requested jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.isSubstring = function(haystack, needle) {
    return haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1;
};
```

Usage:

```
$.isSubstring("hello world", "world")); // true;​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: brilliant! the argument names are now going into my production code.

Comment: That was PHP nostalgia I guess - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php. PHP uses it all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

If your limited to jQuery which is just JavaScript... you can use the filter

```
var subgtSel = $("#jquerySelector").filter(function(i) {
    // do your filter here
    return $(this).attr("data-timestamp") <= subMsg.CreateDateTimeStamp;
});
```

the `subgtSel` becomes your new jQuery now with the relevant filter in the above. In the above, I am looking for all div elements that have an attribute that is less than the subMsg.CreateTimeStamp.

If your looking for a particular substring... you can do the following with jQuery right in the selector

```
var sel = $("#jquerySelector:contains('text')");
```

see http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/